# Is there a way to use Bind9 $GENERATE directive for rDNS of ranges bigger than /24?

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, bind, subnet, reverse-dns

The $GENERATE directive of bind9 makes it possible to autogenerate the reverse mapping for a range of IPs what is really helpfull for reverse dns of a dhcp range. But it seems that the $GENERATE directive can only generate the reverse dns for a /24 subnet. So is there an easy way to autogenerate the reverse mapping for example the range of a /18 subnet whitout a zone file with more than 16k lines?

A solution with another DNS server or a way without $GENERATE is also welcome.

**Hint:** The whole reverse zone is a /16 not a /18 but I only need to generate the rDNS PTR RR for the range of a /18.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to nest `$GENERATE`, if that is what you were going for.  `$GENERATE` in itself creates a sequence for a single range of numbers, not necessarily a /24 in the case of use for reverse zones but not multiple ranges at once (although [there are modifiers available](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2601644) that can be used to modify the output to some extent).

However, you couldn't have a /18 network as a single reverse zone anyway, it would be 64 /24 zones.

This is simply based on how IPv4 addresses are mapped to names (eg, `192.0.2.1` -> `1.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa`). Based on this mapping, delegation can only happen at the octet boundaries, meaning that zones can only be created for /32, /24, /16 and /8.

(There is the CNAME based solution for sub /24 zones described in [rfc2317](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2317) but it's really a last resort to deal with small networks that otherwise would be difficult to deal with at all.)

Seeing as you have added information that it is in fact a /16 reverse zone where you want to add records for just a part of your network you could add 64 $GENERATE directives.

An example for something like 10.0.0.0/18:

```
$GENERATE 0-255 $.0 PTR $.foo.
$GENERATE 0-255 $.1 PTR $.bar.
...
$GENERATE 0-255 $.63 PTR $.baz.
```

Comment: Well I meant that I want to generate the rDNS for the **range** of a /18 not that I have a reverse zone with the size of a /18. The whole reverse zone is a /16.

Comment: @nazco Ok, good to have that clarified. An option could be to stick 64 $GENERATE directives in there.

Comment: Ok, I've already expected that this would be the only way but I hope to find a solution with only one directive.